# Excel stops working, can't find the mistake

Tags: excel, error-handling, vba

My VBA procedure stops working every time I run it. I just can't find the mistake.
There is no error message; Excel just stops working.

Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Public newestFile As Object

Sub Scan_Click()
    Dim row As Integer: row = 2

    Do
        If Sheets("ETA File Server").Cells(row, 1) <> "" Then
            Dim path As String: path = Sheets("ETA File Server").Cells(row, 1)
            If Sheets("ETA File Server").Cells(row, 1) = "Root" Then
                row = row + 1
            Else
                Call getNewestFile(path)
                Sheets("ETA File Server").Cells(row, 10) = newestFile.Name
                Sheets("ETA File Server").Cells(row, 9) = newestFile.DateLastModified
                row = row + 1
            End If
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
    row = 2

End Sub

Private Sub getNewestFile(folderPath As String)
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object

    'get the filesystem object from the system
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(folderPath)


    'go through the subfolder and call itself
    For Each objFile In objFolder.SubFolders
        Call getNewestFile(objFile.path)
    Next

    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If newestFile Is Nothing Then
            Set newestFile = objFile
        ElseIf objFile.DateLastModified > newestFile.DateLastModified Then
            Set newestFile = objFile
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: do you understand the code you have? you made your `do...loop` possible to work over 1.000.000 times end each time it will call other Sub. It's difficult to help you if we don't see your sheets, workbooks, etc. The only idea I have- try to run it with `F8` which is a kind of debugging option...

Comment: in the recursion `For Each objFile In objFolder.Files`- are you sure you are not getting back files "." and ".." ... if you do, you must exclude them from the finds, because they point to themselves ... set a breakpoint at `Sub getNewestFile()` (F9) step thru with F8 and inspect object `objFile` using the Local window after each cycle.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code in debug mode? Do that, and let us know what you find out.

Comment: yeah i did debug the code, i think the problem is the amount of data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some changes to your code. This will slow your process down a bit but it shouldn't crash. I tested it for 5 rows of data i.e `5 main folders` (*6883 subfolders, 46413 files*) and it ran just fine.

Once your test is over, delete the lines which have `subfoldercount` or `filescount` in them

```
Option Explicit

Public newestFile As Object
Dim subfoldercount As Long, filescount As Long

Sub Scan_Click()
    Dim path As String
    Dim row As Integer: row = 2
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ETA File Server")

    subfoldercount = 0: filescount = 0

    With ws
        Do
            If .Cells(row, 1).Value = "" Then Exit Do

            path = .Cells(row, 1).Value

            Application.StatusBar = "Processing folder " & path
            DoEvents

            If Not .Cells(row, 1).Value = "Root" Then
                Call getNewestFile(path)

                .Cells(row, 7).Value = subfoldercount
                .Cells(row, 8).Value = filescount
                .Cells(row, 9).Value = newestFile.DateLastModified
                .Cells(row, 10).Value = newestFile.Name

                Set newestFile = Nothing
                subfoldercount = 0: filescount = 0
                row = row + 1
            End If
        Loop
    End With

    Application.StatusBar = "Done"
End Sub

Private Sub getNewestFile(folderPath As String)
    Dim objFSO As Object, objFolder As Object, objFile As Object

    'get the filesystem object from the system
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(folderPath)

    'go through the subfolder and call itself
    For Each objFile In objFolder.SubFolders
        subfoldercount = subfoldercount + 1
        Call getNewestFile(objFile.path)
        DoEvents
    Next


    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        filescount = filescount + 1
        If newestFile Is Nothing Then
            Set newestFile = objFile
        ElseIf objFile.DateLastModified > newestFile.DateLastModified Then
            Set newestFile = objFile
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I did change it, it's still not working, i think it is because of the amount of data. I changed the `code`If not `code` because it did not work, and i also hat to add a row = row + 1, because it did not go on whitout...
after the first two lines it stops writing in cells, but the script is still running...that may be a sign that Excel is overstrained.

Comment: another prblem appears, it seems that the paths are too long for one string, should it break the path in more parts or is there a better solution?